# Sheets - click on a cell and return filtered list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of objectives on one tab and a list of risks on another tab. Those risks are mapped to objectives in a many to many relationship where one risk may have multiple affected objectives and one objective may have multiple associated risk.

I want to click on an objective ID and return the list of associated risks. I've found a way to do this manually by using the FILTER function (with either FIND or SEARCH), but I have to manually create a dedicated tab per set of objective-specific risks, and that can be tedious.

I'm wondering if anyone has ideas on how I can optimize this? Perhaps using Apps Script?

EDIT: Ideally I would keep the headings and formatting of my risks tab. Maybe I am asking for too much though :)

Comment: If you already have a working formula, you can use a single tab, and use FILTER with a cell reference. Let's say you have A1 with a dropdown menu with all the IDs, you choose one and in the next rows the FILTER function grabs this value and displays the associated risks